# Added wrong drive to raid1 via mdadm, partition recovery

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, hard-drive, mdadm

My raid is functioning fine, but I accidentally added a USB drive to what is a sata RAID1 with mdadm.

I noticed this pretty quickly and removed the drive from raid, it was synced about half a percent. Its can't be mounted as xfs because the partition table was overwritten and I'm trying to recover whatever data I can.

Using blkid, the original type was xfs, but it's now a type of linux_raid_member with a label of the raid name and a UUID_SUB.

I tried using parted with `set 1 raid off` but that didn't help. Any way I can recreate the old partition table to get any possible data off it? Or at least change the type back to xfs? I can see a majority of the files with `xfs_check`

Both the raid drives and the USB drive have just one gpt partition with xfs and a block size of 512.

Comment: restore from backup

Comment: Restoring partition table doesnt help you because large part of filesystem is overwritten. You only may scan entire partition with xfs aware soft to maybe get some files.

Comment: I don't have a backup of the partition table. Not much was overwritten. What xfs software can help me retrieve some files?

Comment: xfs_repair worked, though it's not easy identifying folders by their ID instead of their path/name